# Why selecting text in my notebook become abnormal?

Tags: notebooks

Selecting text in one of my Notebooks becomes abnormal.

Here is the unselected text:

[image]

and here is the partly selected text:

[image]

When the text being selected, it should be like this:

[image]

What is wrong with this Notebook? my other Notebook is OK!

[Here is my abnormal Notebook.](http://ge.tt/49cqoAm/v/0?c?c)

Comment: Behavior confirmed in version 7, but I don't know what is causing it.

Comment: Similar behavior in V9.0.1 on OS X 10.5.8

Comment: If I do a Select All on the downloaded notebook, copy the selection, and paste it into a new notebook, highlighting works as expected in the new notebook. Perhaps you can do the same to recover control over your work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to local situation and needs of its poster.

Comment: @m_goldberg You may have noticed that "too localized" is no longer a listed reason for closing. ;-)  Anyway, in this case I disagree as it's a curious problem until the solution is revealed, and it could potentially affect anyone who comes across such a Notebook.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I noticed, but rm -rf has encouraged me to to continue to use it when it seems applicable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your notebook has an option set, `ShowSelection -> False`, which is causing the problem.  Use the Format > Option Inspector... and search for `ShowSelection`; then click the checkbox to set it to `True`.  Or execute `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ShowSelection -> True]` in the notebook.

Comment: Nice catch!  I don't think I've ever seen that option before.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard why it doesn't work for me? The option is false, but I can't make it True. Because it is grey! After I ran "SetOption[EvaluationNotebook[], ShowSelection -> True]", the option is changable. But just for one time. When I look it second time, it becomes false again.

Comment: @matheorem It worked for me; I used the Option Inspector, chose **Selected Notebook** in the drop-down menu, and then found the option by typing it in the search field.  I reset the option by clicking the "X" to the left of option name.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard "choose Selected Notebook", this step is essential to success. Thank you Mr.Wizard !